# Best way to resume aborted cnc job without endstops by zeroing in on known hole…?

Tags: cnc

I have a very simple little T8 CNC without endstops that I use for PCB's. After a failed drill job, the position of the machine is lost and I would like to resume the job.

The machine is running GRBL 0.9 and I'm using UGS for sending the gcode.

So I would like to be able to jog the machine to match a known hole that's already been drilled and then say "hey, you're now at position x, y", but I can't seem to find either a gcode or function in UGS to do this. Is there any such gcode?

My workaround is currently to jog to a known hole, reset to zero, then send gcode to move to the inversion of that known hole and set zero again. Is there any smarter way?

Comment: G codes are not universal. They depend on machine. Does your system not have work offsets (G54-G59)? If so just adjust the work offset by inverse of how much you jogged. But yes the way you did it is how coordinate transforms are normally composed.